# How to create an associative array in following case?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm having few arrays as follows. Actually I'm having too many such arrays but for your reference I've printed only few of them:

```
Array
(
    [0] => lineItemData
    [1] => name
)
Array
(
    [0] => lineItemData
    [1] => startDate
)
Array
(
    [0] => lineItemData
    [1] => endDate
)
Array
(
    [0] => lineItemData
    [1] => frequencyCapping
    [2] => interval
)
Array
(
    [0] => lineItemData
    [1] => frequencyCapping
    [2] => amount
)
Array
(
    [0] => orderId
)
Array
(
    [0] => isExternal
)
```

Now you can observe in man of the above arrays key value `[lineItemData]` is common and it is present at oth index. Now I want to create a new array where the key would be `[lineItemData]` and other arrays which don't have a value `[lineItemData]` present within themselves should be new keys and other keys should be keys under every key. My question may confuse you. So I'm printing below the desired output array

```
Array
(
    [lineItemData] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [startDate] => 
            [endDate] =>
            [frequencyCapping] => Array
            (
                [interval] => 
                [amount] => 
            )   

        )
    [orderId] => 
    [isExternal] => 

)
```

Comment: And what about values in your array? From where they're derived? (in your result sample you have only keys, which is incorrect)

Comment: @AlmaDo:Actually I want to built up the above array with the keys as I said. Then from the form I'll assign the values to it. But before assigning valus I need to have this array structure prepared.

Comment: So you don't care about values (at least at creation)?

Comment: @AlmaDo:Yes, until the desired array structure gets created I'm not worried about values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
$data = [
   ['lineItemData', 'name'],
   ['lineItemData', 'startDate'],
   ['lineItemData', 'endDate'],
   ['lineItemData', 'frequencyCapping', 'interval'],
   ['lineItemData', 'frequencyCapping', 'amount'],
   ['orderId'],
   ['isExternal']
];

$result  = [];
$pointer = &$result;

foreach($data as $keys)
{
   foreach($keys as $key)
   {
      if(is_array($pointer) && !array_key_exists($key, $pointer))
      {
         $pointer[$key] = null;
      }
      $pointer = &$pointer[$key];
   }
   $pointer = &$result;
}
```

End result will look like:

```
array(3) {
  ["lineItemData"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["startDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["endDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["frequencyCapping"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["interval"]=>
      NULL
      ["amount"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
  ["orderId"]=>
  NULL
  ["isExternal"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: :Can you please explain me how you did create $data array at the beginning of your answer?

Comment: Huh..? With my hands. It has structure, identical to your original array (only my have not numeric keys, directly coded)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like so?

```
    <?php
    $super['lineItemData']['name'] = NULL;
    $super['lineItemData']['startDate'] = NULL;
    $super['lineItemData']['endDate'] = NULL;
    $super['lineItemData']['frequencyCapping']['interval'] = NULL;
    $super['lineItemData']['frequencyCapping']['amount'] = NULL;
    $super['orderId'] = NULL; 
    $super['isExternal'] = NULL; ?>
```

I'm sure someone will get crafty and find a way to make this happen in one `array` statement. I like this because it's easier for me to manage.

Comment: Actually, first of all I want logic to work dynamically. That is it should be able to first find out the 0th key which is common in many of the arrays and then the logic of creation of subsequent keys/arrays. The logic you wrote above is for static manipulatuion of array.

Comment: Use `$super[]` instead of just `$super`. I think that's what you are looking for. Example: `$super[]['lineItemData']['endDate'] = NULL;`

Another option it to popular `$super` and then add the multi-dimensional array to another variable to stack it up: `$stack[] = $super`